# Get notifications of DevOps VM updates like ubuntu:latest with node 18

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, push-notification, azure-pipelines, updates

can you support me, where I could have found the information that Feb 21, 2023 there was a node version update in the ubuntu VM using in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

As this caused that our pipelines failed I would like to be informed upfront but no one in our company received a notification about that, so how can I activate it?

Thank you!

Regards,

Vanessa

At 22nd Feb I searched in the following links but did not find an entry about node 18 update - which was even too late:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/alerting-and-notifications-support-for-windows-azure-applications/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-updates-for-your-azure-vm/

Expectation:

- get notified before such a critical update if it crashes our pipelines
- at the 22nd Feb find an entry in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/? about the node 18 update
- be able to add subscription to that page with filters - I have no clue what and how to do that, when I click "Log in" because then I am on a totally different page

> I know that now there is an entry available but it was not on 22nd Feb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Hosted build agents are regularly updated with the latest versions of developer tools. These agents run many tools and it would be impractical to inform customers of version updates. MS will not notify you as a general rule, although occasionally they will provide information such as removing older agent images from the pool (e.g. when they removed ubuntu-18.04 images). You can see [the code used by MS to generate the agent images](https://github.com/actions/runner-images) which will give you an idea of when things are changed. It looks like Node 18 was set to the default on [February 12th](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/commit/632145f3a53b1c2ee55e51d204dd70530bb95e35)

Where you need a specific version of a tool such as node, you can often add a task to your pipeline to specify the version required.

for Node there is a task called NodeTool which can be added to a pipeline to say which version the build should use

```
          - task: NodeTool@0
            displayName: 'Use node 16.19.1'
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '16.19.1'
```

When this runs it will make sure the version specified is used. You can use this task to decide for yourself when to upgrade to a newer version

[image: Node Tool]